# Far Cry 4 Downloading when I have the disc?

Tags: xbox-one, far-cry-4

Today I got an Xbox One and Far Cry 4. I just set it up and put in the disc and it said installing. It's about 24 GB and that's gonna take some time to download if that what it means. Is it like that with all Xbox One games, or do I have a problem. I have the disc so I shouldn't have a problem right? My Xbox 360 didn't download games unless I didn't have the disc. Is this normal?

Comment: Installing is different from Downloading since the latter requires a net connection. some games (even on the PS3) require you to install some of the game even when you have the disk (ie. Metal Gear Solid 4). having not played Far Cry 4 (or that many disk based games on XBOne or PS4) i'm not entirely sure if it's normal or not, i remember Knack on PS4 wanting to install when i had the disk but i can't remember if Assassin's Creed Unity needed to on XBOne

Comment: Asking about specific games is fine.  Asking how every game, across both 360 and XBone, is far too broad for useful answers.  I'd recommend just focusing on Far Cry 4.

Comment: That's fairly normal really, even happens on PC, plus you have to consider the patches that were released.  There was a lot of hotfixes when it first came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the normal installation that each game goes through to run at optimal settings, it will take no internet and can be done offline.

Comment: The OP might have encountered the message that a patch needs to be downloaded. When a patch is available and the console is connected, you will be notified to install the patch before the installation. That way your game is ready and up-to-date after the installation.